# How to clear webview cache every 'n' number days/hours

Tags: java, android, webview

I have cache-enabled webview and want to save info in cache.
I need to clear cache if files in android cache folder are older than 'n' days/hours

I tried code below:

```
static int clearCacheFolder(final File dir, final int numDays) {

    int deletedFiles = 0;
    if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            for (File child:dir.listFiles()) {

                //first delete subdirectories recursively
                if (child.isDirectory()) {
                    deletedFiles += clearCacheFolder(child, numDays);
                }

                //then delete the files and subdirectories in this dir
                //only empty directories can be deleted, so subdirs have been done first
                if (child.lastModified() < new Date().getTime() - numDays * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                    if (child.delete()) {
                        deletedFiles++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Failed to clean the cache, error %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    return deletedFiles;
}
```

Then i use it like this in **onCreate** before calling **WebView.loadUrl()**

```
clearCacheFolder(MainActivity.this.getCacheDir(), 1);
```

But for some reason this is not working...

I believe that there will be some simple method to calculate age of files inside cache folder and delete them if they are older than 'n' days/hours

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: @Basil Bourque function returns no errors but not clear cache folder.

Comment: Post details as edits to your Question, not as Comments. And be more specific: Did you find any files deleted? Did you encounter exceptions? What do your logs report? Did you verify the values of your `Date` calculations?

Comment: @BasilBourque my android webview app gets image links from server webview parses image content once and saves in cache when i update content in server for example upload new image with same name as first one, lets say old image name: 0.jpg and new image name: 0.jpg  (but they are different images just with same names) then problem occurs because webview loads old image from cache but not updated.